# Is it just not possible to have a celery server respond immediately to a message?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have several celery servers with one worker each.  The workers are busy doing long (8hr; I can't split it up) tasks.  I want to be able to tell each server to do something immediately; but it looks like that's genuinely not possible - broadcast would put a task to be executed after the current one finishes, I believe?

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. The workers are busy; what do you want them to do?

Comment: I want the celery app to close itself. (And restart after updating.)

Comment: That is completely different from your original question.

Comment: I already have the ability for it to close itself, update, and restart - I just can't get it to call that functionality on time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by having a special queue with, say, allocated 1 worker process. By default nothing goes to this queue unless you need something done immediately.

[celery.bin.multi reference page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html#module-celery.bin.multi) shows how this can be done.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good, thank you - how do you start a celery server with two workers but on different queues?  I currently use
celery -A workerTasks worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info -Q office -f /logs/celery.log

Comment: Oh you just run it twice, fine.